# Property from attr_accessor does not show when I render json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, attr-accessor

In Rails, I have a User model. I added `attr_accessor :score`to the model.

If I render the JSON for one user, I do not see the "score" attribute. Why is this?

```
user = User.find(3)
user.score = 55
render json: user
```

Comment: `render json: user, methods: [:score]`

Comment: @test - just shows an empty object

Comment: I have updated that line. Please check with this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
render json: user, methods: [:score]
```

attr_accessor is alternative for getter and setter method so it is a method and as I have mentioned we can call it as above

Comment: Is there any way to do this with an array of objects?

Comment: @ricks To do this with an array of objects, I used as_json: `render json: { invites: invites.as_json(methods: [:amount]) }`