# Rails attr_accessor's dissapear when converting array of objects to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :total_cost
end
```

This is my controller where i am fetching the Orders:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def fetch_orders

        data = Order.all

        data_with_appended_fields = append_calculated_fields(data)

        render json: { success: true, data: data_with_appended_fields}
    end

private 

    def append_calculated_fields(data)

        new_data = data.each do |order|

            order.total_cost = 10
        end

        new_data
    end

end
```

In my method `append_calculated_fields` when i print `new_data.to_json` the `attr_accessor` field that i added is not inside of the JSON.

When i print `order.total_cost` after setting it, it shows the value `10`.

Am i approaching this the wrong way?

I am trying to add calculated fields to the **array of objects** and returning the data with the calculated values.

Was able to return `new_data.to_json(:methods => [:total_cost])`and got my required output.

Comment: If you are using Rails 5+ you should use the [attributes api](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/12/11/rails-5-attributes-api.html) instead of `attr_accessor`. `attribute :total_cost, :integer`.

Comment: ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON does not "pick up" attributes defined with attr_accessor in ActiveRecord models.

Comment: Why did you do this in controller?

Comment: @max Is there any way i can return this data with the attributes? in the line `render json: { success: true, data: data_with_appended_fields}`

Comment: @mechnicov should i move this to the model?

Comment: It's better to use such methods in models or sevices. Controllers are for requests

Comment: What is this even supposed to do? You're just setting `total_cost = 10` for every record.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property from attr\_accessor does not show when I render json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641623/property-from-attr-accessor-does-not-show-when-i-render-json)

Comment: You could do `attribute :total_cost, :integer, default: 10`. But I'm guessing what you really want to do is something like `Order.joins(:line_items).select('orders.*, SUM(line_items.cost) AS total_cost')` as having a fixed cost for every order just seems stupid. Or maybe I just don't understand your domain.

Comment: @max its just an example, i need to return calculated fields using different values from the orders object. I didn't want to do it in the active record query so that i can do it server side and not have to calculate using the DB.

Comment: @mechnicov, similar issue but that person was doing it with one object, i just tried with my array of objects and it did not work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add virtual attribute to json output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892044/add-virtual-attribute-to-json-output)

Comment: Found the answer in that thread, i just didn't know how to properly word this issue to find the solution. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: By the way the way you've written `append_calculated_fields` mutates the records and so it's unnecessary to return anything from that method. You can just call `append_calculated_fields(data)` (not using the return value) and use `data: data` in the JSON response. This won't solve your issue but it's more idiomatic